# CORS is enabling for login and next api and failing for all other APIs

Tags: node.js, reactjs, cors

I am implementing a React application and node server as a backend. Recently I have updated my chrome version. And also updated some APIs but I haven't done any changes regarding CORS. But from Yesterday login request and the next request is getting success (I mean requests on the load of the application) after that any request that is fired due to event in the browser is failing.

All requests on load of the applications is a success when I go to any other routes by clicking on link API calls in that route Component are failing. I don't understand the reason for getting success on load and getting CORS error on any event-based API request?

My options req/res headers are

Request:

```
Request URL: http://localhost:4000/apps
Request Method: OPTIONS
Status Code: 204 No Content
Remote Address: [::1]:4000
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
```

Res Headers:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: authorization,orgid
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 0
Date: Sun, 02 Aug 2020 06:58:37 GMT
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=15552000; includeSubDomains
Vary: Access-Control-Request-Headers
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-DNS-Prefetch-Control: off
X-Download-Options: noopen
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
```

Req Headers:

```
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Access-Control-Request-Headers: authorization,orgid
Access-Control-Request-Method: GET
Connection: keep-alive
Host: localhost:4000
Origin: http://localhost:3000
Referer: http://localhost:3000/apps/list
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-site
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.105 Safari/537.36 Edg/84.0.522.52
```

This request is always getting success.

But I have another request  (this req is failing with CORS)

Req:

```
Request URL: http://localhost:4000/rs
Request Method: OPTIONS
Status Code: 204 No Content
Remote Address: [::1]:4000
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
```

res Headers"

```
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: appid,authorization
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 0
Date: Sun, 02 Aug 2020 06:59:21 GMT
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=15552000; includeSubDomains
Vary: Access-Control-Request-Headers
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-DNS-Prefetch-Control: off
X-Download-Options: noopen
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
```

Req Headers:

```
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Access-Control-Request-Headers: appid,authorization
Access-Control-Request-Method: GET
Connection: keep-alive
Host: localhost:4000
Origin: http://localhost:3000
Referer: http://localhost:3000/apps/rs/list

Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-site
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.105 Safari/537.36 Edg/84.0.522.52
```

I have enabled CORS in node API like,

```
let cors = require('cors')
app.use(cors());
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    next();
});
//routes start from here
```

Error message:

```
Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:4000/rs' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

Failed GET request headers,

```
Request URL: http://localhost:4000/rs
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
```

res Headers:

```
Connection: close
```

req Headers:

```
Accept: application/json
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,te;q=0.8
Authorization: Bearer eyJpZCI6IjVkNTE5NjFlNWMzMDM1NDlkNDYwZjk
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: application/json
Host: localhost:4000
orgId: 5dca073d4b044330e44e7946
Origin: http://localhost:3001
Referer: http://localhost:3001/apps/
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-site
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.105 Safari/537.36
```

Comment: Let's consider I am in route `localhost:3000/rs`, it fetches all rs records from API (`localhost:4000/rs`). When I click on any rs record in UI table route changes to `localhost:3000/rs/rsid` now API (`localhost:4000/rs/rsid`) request fails. Now id I refresh the browser where route is localhost:3000/rs/rsid here APi request is getting success (`localhost:4000/rs/rsid`). Same request failing on event click but getting success on refresh.

Answer (score 0):

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"); // "*" means allow connection from any request url.
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    next();
});
```

You can change the `*` with the allowed url.

Or try this [cors tutorial](https://daveceddia.com/access-control-allow-origin-cors-errors-in-react-express/) make sure to whitelist your request url. In your case 'http://localhost:3000'

```
// Set up a whitelist and check against it:
var whitelist = ['http://localhost:3000']
var corsOptions = {
    origin: function (origin, callback) {
        if (whitelist.indexOf(origin) !== -1) {
            callback(null, true)
        } else {
            callback(new Error('Not allowed by CORS'))
        }
    }
}

// Then pass them to cors:
app.use(cors(corsOptions));
```

Comment: I tried with these still requests are getting CORS issue

`Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:4000/rs' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.`

Comment: I think the problem is that you set the request cors mode to fetch from `same-site`. I can see that localhost:3000 is not the same site as localhost:4000. Your request expect it to get response from the same site which is localhost:3000 not 4000.

Comment: Page on load requests are getting success and even my login request getting success everytime.

Comment: Let's consider I am in route `localhost:3000/rs`, it fetches all `rs` records from API (`localhost:4000/rs`). When I click on any rs record in UI table route changes to `localhost:3000/rs/rsid` now API (`localhost:4000/rs/rsid`) request fails. Now id I refresh the browser where route is `localhost:3000/rs/rsid` here APi request is getting success (`localhost:4000/rs/rsid`). Same request failing on event click but getting success on refresh.

Comment: Looking at your request `Sec-Fetch-Site: same-site` here means that your UI server expect to get data from the same site which is localhost:3000. Actually what bothers me is why does it even success on getting the data from localhost:4000, it should be failing.

Comment: I think  maybe it  has something to do with authorization and appid headers passing through.

Comment: Try to clear your browser cache, or do it from `incognito mode`, let see if that works

Answer (score 0):

You don't require all that to send an http request. This is a basic example.

It should be like this:

> Server.js

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');

var app = express();
app.use(cors());

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.json({'Hello':'World'});
});

app.listen(3000);
```

> Client..html

```
<html>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $.get("http://localhost:3000/", function(response) {
            console.log(resposne);
        });
    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: He probably wants to get from `http://localhost:4000`.

Comment: I just gave him an example.

Comment: I am already using `app.use(cors());` and using `fetch` to make API requests. Server running on 4000 and (react) UI running on 3000

Comment: Try this example. It won't show you cors error in your browser. And later, follow the rules.